# Number formatting on Y axis in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I am creating SSRS below report, but Y axis I am getting values with more zeros. I tried to change the number format but still I  am getting the below values with more zeros. My actual on y axis is under 5000.

[image]

How can get rid of the extra zeros from Y axis.

Thanks

Comment: What data do you have in your dataset? aggregate received values and see if there isn`t some error in the query.

Comment: If the counts aren't distinct, it looks like you might be summing them. Try changing the aggregate to First.

Comment: Steven : You got it right.. While choosing the field, it was choosing SUM by default..then I changed the aggregate function ..it is working fine now...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a custom number formatting to scale them back. Set your custom formatting to `10,,` should do it.